# Display inline block has a gap above the second div

Tags: html, css

I am having a bit of a problem with display inline block, basically I have 2 divs and i want to position them next to each other, however there is a gap above the second div called (#store_header_text) I have no idea why there is a gap - I just can't seem to get my head around this one.

I have tried by removing the position : absolute and relative on the other divs around it, however this had no effect.

[Here is Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6kx0wot7/)

My HTML:

```
<div id="store_header">

        <div id="store_header_logo">

            <a href="http://www.amazon.co.uk">
                <img class="store_header_img" src="/images/tiles/amazon.png" title="Amazon"></img>
            </a>


        </div>

        <div id="store_header_text">
            Amazon Coupons & Deals
        </div>

</div>
```

My CSS:

```
#store_header {
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    background-color:#fff;
    border-radius:3px;
    padding:5px;
}

#store_header_logo {
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;

    border:1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;


}



#store_header_logo img {
    max-height: 90px;  
    max-width: 180px; 
    top: 0;  
    bottom: 0;  
    left: 0;  
    right: 0;  
    margin: auto;  
    background: #3A6F9A; 
    position: absolute;

    border:1px solid black;




}

#store_header_text {
    height:100px;
    width:300px;
    line-height: 90px;
    padding-left:20px;
    font-size:25px;
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;  
    font-weight:400;
    color:#004d6e;
    display: inline-block;
    border:1px solid black;


}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6kx0wot7/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

without modifying your codes much, add

```
vertical-align: top;
```

in your `#store_header_logo` id

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6kx0wot7/2/)

Comment: I have no idea why, but that worked perfectly, Thankyou Andrew

Comment: @BradleyCousins That is because default value of `vertical-align` is `baseline` so it aligns according to the baseline of the container.

Answer (score 1):

Tweaked a couple of things. Changed inline-block to inline primarily

```css
#store_header {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.store_header_logo {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline;
}
.store_header_logo img {
  max-height: 90px;
  max-width: 180px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: #3A6F9A;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.store_header_text {
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  line-height: 90px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #004d6e;
  display: inline;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="store_header">

  <div class="store_header_logo">

    <a href="http://www.amazon.co.uk">
      <img class="store_header_img" src="/images/tiles/amazon.png" title="Amazon"></img>
    </a>


  </div>

  <div class="store_header_text">
    Amazon Coupons & Deals
  </div>





</div>
```